# Any visa for the help forTurkish people this time Erthquick for me i want go

Tags: pakistani-citizens, turkish-citizens

Turkish government.inform me on this email .

Comment: This is not a site a government will post information on. Better check embassy and consulate website.

Answer (score 10):

I'm an American Red Cross volunteer. I am not involved in the response to the response in Turkey or Syria. Our training, given long before this recent earthquake, is that the best way for most people outside the disaster area to help is to donate to high-quality charities.

For basic disaster work such as carrying materials, cooking, putting up tents, and the like the most effective way for charities to help is to pay local people to do this. That way there is money injected into the local economy and there is no additional burden on local resources (food, water, shelter).

Charities and governments outside the disaster area usually send people with special skills, for example, teams with special equipment to rescue people from collapsed buildings.

Comment: Fully agree. Random untrained people without external logistics support are a burden, not a help.

Comment: In the best of cases, OP may offer to volunteer through an established NGO in their own country, but it’s unlikely they would send untrained people to what is a dangerous area where they may be hampering actual rescue efforts.